# parse_timestamp vs format_timestamp bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Could someone help me understand why these two queries are returning different results in bigquery?

`select FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%F %H:%M:%E*S', "2018-10-01 00:00:00" , 'Europe/London')`
returns 2018-10-01 01:00:00

`select PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%F %H:%M:%E*S', "2018-10-0100:00:00", "Europe/London")`
returns 2018-09-30 23:00:00 UTC

As 2018-10-01 is during british summer time (UTC +1), I would've expected both queries to return 2018-09-30 23:00:00 UTC

Comment: The first function returns string while the second one returns timestamp (build from string). Timestamp display may depend on your local timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is given a timestamp which is in UTC.  It then converts it to the corresponding time in Europe/London.  The return value is a string representing the time in the local timezone.

The second takes a string representation and returns a UTC timestamp.  The representation is assumed to be in Europe/London.

So, the two functions are going in different directions, one from UTC to the local time and the other from the local time to UTC.